# Django 1.11 url pattern error, how to solve?

Tags: python, regex, django

When I try to fix the url in my `urlpatterns` it shows me this error :

The error:

> Your URL pattern "url(r'^player/[?P[-\w\x20]+]/$', PlayerDetailView.as_view(), name='player-detail-view'),"
>   is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of url() instance.
>   try removing the string 'url(r'^player/[?P[-\w\x20]+]/$', PlayerDetailView.as_view(), name='player-detail-view'),'. The list of urlpatterns should not have a prefix string as the first element.*

My Code :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home-page'),
    url(r'^teams/$', TeamsListView.as_view(), name='teams-list-view'),
    url(r'^scores/$', ScoresListView.as_view(), name='scores-list-view'),
    url(r'^player/[?P<slug>[-\w\x20]+]/$', PlayerDetailView.as_view(), name='player-detail-view'),
]
```

Can anyone help me??

Comment: You should use *round* brackets, *not* square ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is a bit off, you need to use *round* brackets `(..)` instead of *square* brackets `[..]` around a "capture group":

```
url(
    r'^player/(?P<slug>[-\w\x20]+)/$',
    PlayerDetailView.as_view(),
    name='player-detail-view'
),
```

Furthermore if I recall correctly, a *slug* can not contain spaces, so you might want to remove the `\x20`.

Note that in [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0) and higher, the [**`path(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path) function can be used, which has support for slugs like:

```
# Django 2.0 and higher

path('player/<slug:slug>/', PlayerDetailView.as_view(), name='player-detail-view'),
```

Then Django replaces the slug with a *builtin* pattern, which makes the URL patterns more "declarative".

Comment: Willem Van Onsem , Thank you so much its really helpful , and about the " \x20" it works for me but im not convainced with it ! can you explain it to me in a word plz ?